# How to specify uvicorn workers in gunicorn conf file

Tags: django, gunicorn, uvicorn

I run Django app with gunicorn using: `gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py config.wsgi`

```
## gunicorn.conf.py:

from os import environ

bind = '0.0.0.0:' + environ.get('PORT', '8000')
workers = environ.get('WORKERS', 8)
loglevel = 'info'
graceful_timeout = 300
```

Now I run it with gunicorn + uvicorn `gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py config.asgi -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`

and I want the add the `-k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker` to the `gunicorn.conf.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `worker_class = 'uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker'`, Documeted [here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-class)

```
from os import environ

bind = '0.0.0.0:' + environ.get('PORT', '8000')
workers = environ.get('WORKERS', 8)
loglevel = 'info'
graceful_timeout = 300
worker_class = 'uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker'
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class) the setting is named `worker_class`, the following should work

```
worker_class = 'uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker'
```

Comment: Thanks I just found it in the docs then I came back to find your Answer, am gonna keep the question in case people needed that in the future.